# post request not working in react-native redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, redux-thunk

I am trying to call an fake authentication API using axios, when i call action which makes network request.
My flow of action is

1. dispatch loginRequest
2. make api request
3. if successful dispatch loginSuccessful
4. if failure dispatch loginFaliure

It first calls the `loginRequest` action then it doesn't call any action not even `loginFaliure`
but if i check network tab the request is successful 
if i make get request, all actions dispatch as they should

i have tried fetch,.then with axios

> App.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import reducers from './src/store/reducers';
import LoginPage from './src/components/pages/Login';
// import './src/config/ReactotronConfig';
// import Reactotron from 'reactotron-react-native';

// To see all the requests in the chrome Dev tools in the network tab.
XMLHttpRequest = GLOBAL.originalXMLHttpRequest ? GLOBAL.originalXMLHttpRequest : GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest;

// fetch logger
global._fetch = fetch;
global.fetch = function(uri, options, ...args) {
    return global._fetch(uri, options, ...args).then(response => {
        console.log('Fetch', { request: { uri, options, ...args }, response });
        return response;
    });
};

// redux integration
const middleware = [thunk];
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    middleware.push(createLogger());
}

const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(...middleware));

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        // Reactotron.log('hello from AppContainer');

        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <LoginPage />
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

> reducers

```js
import { LOGIN_REQUEST, LOGIN_SUCCESS, LOGIN_FAILURE, LOGOUT_REQUEST } from '../constants/auth';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

// _retrieveData = async () => {
//  try {
//      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
//      if (value !== null) {
//          // We have data!!
//          return value;
//      }
//      return null;
//  } catch (error) {
//      // Error retrieving data
//      console.log('error fetching token', error);
//  }
// };

// const isuser =  _retrieveData();

const isuser = null;

const innitialState = {
    token: isuser ? isuser : null,
    userName: isuser ? 'ketan kulkarni' : null,
    isAuthenticated: isuser ? true : false,
    isAuthenticating: false,
    statusText: isuser ? 'Logged In' : null,
};

export const auth = (state = innitialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOGIN_REQUEST:
            return { ...state, isAuthenticating: true };
        case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                token: action.token,
                userName: action.userName,
                isAuthenticating: false,
                isAuthenticated: true,
                statusText: 'You have been successfully logged in',
            };
        case LOGIN_FAILURE:
            return {
                ...state,
                token: null,
                userName: null,
                isAuthenticated: false,
                isAuthenticating: false,
                statusText: `Authentication Error ${action.status} ${action.statusText}`,
            };
        case LOGOUT_REQUEST:
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: false,
                token: null,
                userName: null,
                statusText: 'You have been successfully logged out.',
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

> actions

```js
import { LOGIN_REQUEST, LOGIN_SUCCESS, LOGIN_FAILURE, LOGOUT_REQUEST } from '../constants/auth';
import axios from 'axios';

export const loginRequest = () => ({
    type: LOGIN_REQUEST,
});

export const loginSuccess = title => {
    return {
        type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
        token: title,
        username: 'ketan',
    };
};

export const loginFailure = error => {
    return {
        type: LOGIN_FAILURE,
        status: 'error.response.status',
        statusText: 'login failed',
    };
};

export const logout = () => {
    return { type: LOGOUT_REQUEST };
};

export const loginUser = (email, password) => async dispatch => {
    dispatch(loginRequest());
    try {
        console.log('requesting');
        const res = await axios.get(`https://reqres.in/api/login`, { email, password });
        console.log('request done', res);
        //decode token then
        dispatch(loginSuccess('data'));
    } catch (error) {
        console.log({ error });
        dispatch(loginFailure(error));
    }
    // setTimeout(() => {
    //  if (1) dispatch(loginSuccess('data'));
    // }, 2000);

    // axios
    //  .post(`https://reqres.in/api/login`, { email, password })
    //  .then(() => dispatch(loginSuccess('data')))
    //  .catch(err => dispatch(loginFailure(err)));

    // fetch('https://reqres.in/api/login', {
    //     method: 'GET',
    //     headers: {
    //         Accept: 'application/json',
    //         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    //     },
    //     body: JSON.stringify({
    //         email,
    //         password,
    //     }),
    // })
    //     .then(() => dispatch(loginSuccess('data')))
    //     .catch(err => dispatch(loginFailure(err)));
};
```

> loginPage

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { loginUser } from '../../store/actions/auth';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class LoginPage extends Component {
    _onPressButton = async () => {
        await this.props.dispatch(loginUser('eve.holt@reqres.in', 'cityslicka'));
        console.log('here');
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                    <Button onPress={this._onPressButton} title="Press Me" />
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(null)(LoginPage);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    buttonContainer: {
        margin: 20,
    },
    alternativeLayoutButtonContainer: {
        margin: 20,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
    },
});
```

> Expected output-

first dipatch loginRequest
if api request is successful dispatch loginSuccessful
if api request fails dispatch loginFailure

> Actual output -

when making post request
dispatch loginRequest
then no any action gets dispatch

if get request is made
everything works correctly

Answer (score 0):

the code I added in App.js to check network request in network tab was causing the error

```
// To see all the requests in the chrome Dev tools in the network tab.
// XMLHttpRequest = GLOBAL.originalXMLHttpRequest ? GLOBAL.originalXMLHttpRequest : GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest;

// // fetch logger
// global._fetch = fetch;
// global.fetch = function(uri, options, ...args) {
//  return global._fetch(uri, options, ...args).then(response => {
//      console.log('Fetch', { request: { uri, options, ...args }, response });
//      return response;
//  });
// };
```